# .htaccess method of setting a default URL to resolve to?

Tags: php, .htaccess

We have two sites, and we've just now made an in-house development server that we want to have both sites on. What I want to accomplish is to have an `.htaccess` in each of the site folders that prepends the development URL of the site. For example, where they simply have a `header(location: /folder/whatever.php)`, the files should actually go to `thesite/folder/whatever.php`.

Currently what happens is (for example) they'll go to `192.168.x.x/folder/whatever.php`

Comment: To clarify: you always want them to go to the production site when you refer to `/`, and not the site you are developing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly and what you want is to redirect `192.168.x.x/folder/whatever.php` to `thesite/folder/whatever.php`, you could use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^thesite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://thesite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```